# Strange Error with UseSignalR in file Startup.cs

Tags: asp.net-core

I will attach the image that appear the error :

[image]

And the code :

```
    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/ NotificationHub");
        });         
       

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default" ,
               pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=login}/{id?}");
        });
```

How can i fix it or what is the alternative .I'm using Asp.Net core3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly I think your question isn't well fleshed but from what I can deduce. Here is a possible fix.

In your Startup.cs file in side the ConfigureServices and Configure methods do this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // codes removed for brevity.
            services.AddSignalR();
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default" ,
           pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=login}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/NotificationHub");
        });
    }
```

I hope this helps you resolve the error you are getting.